# How can i store multiple keys fetched from firebase in String[]?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This loop is fetching 1 key at a time. I want to store all the keys in `String[]` basically at the end of loop and then use it in `ArrayAdapter` for auto complete text view.

```
fdatabaseuser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener({
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

       String item="";

       for (DataSnapshot list: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
       {
           Object obj= list.getKey();
           item=obj.toString();
       }

       Toast.makeText(GiveActivity.this,item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

Comment: Both of the answers won't work because they have declared the `list` outside the `onDataChange()` method and will be null. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you already have the keys. You can create an `ArrayList` and add items.

```
ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
fdatabaseuser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener({
   @Override

   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      String item="";

      for (DataSnapshot list: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
      {
          Object obj= list.getKey();
          item=obj.toString();
          keys.add(item);
      }

      Toast.makeText(GiveActivity.this,item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> item;
```

Initialise list in the `OnCreate` Method

```
item=new ArrayList<>();
```

Then change this code:

```
fdatabaseuser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener({
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

      for (DataSnapshot list: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
      {
          Object obj= list.getKey();
          item.add(obj.toString();)

      }

      Toast.makeText(GiveActivity.this,item,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, please use the following code:

```
fdatabaseuser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener({
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();;

       for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           String key = ds.getKey();
           list.add(key);
       }
       Log.d("TAG", list);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Remember, the `list` must be declared and updated inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be null, due the asynchronous behaviour of `onDataChange()` which is called even before you are adding those keys to the list.